# Printing Values in a Hash using the conditional operator "for" and Ruby's .each

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

I am attempting to solve what should be a very simple problem in Ruby. My goal is to take the following hash and print values and keys using for loops and the .each method.

```
my_stocks = { 'Apple' => { 'symbol' => 'AAPL', 'price' => 100 },
          'Google' => { 'symbol' => 'GOOG', 'price' => 1150 },
          'Tesla' => { 'symbol' => 'TSLA', 'price' => 295 },
          'Microsoft' => { 'symbol' => 'MSFT', 'price' => 95},
          'Netflix' => { 'symbol' => 'NFLX', 'price' => 300},
          'Facebook' => { 'symbol' => 'FB', 'price' => 175},
          'Amazon' => { 'symbol' => 'AMZN', 'price' => 1250} }
```

So, I'm using this defined method to print the entire hash:

```
def execute_exercise(my_stocks)
for i, j in my_stocks
  puts j
end
end
```

Obviously, this succeeds. What I am trying to do next is, use a for loop to print only the values of keys that exceed 500.

Every solution I've come up with raises an error in Ruby:

```
rbtest.rb:18:in `>': no implicit conversion of Fixnum into Hash (TypeError)
from rbtest.rb:18:in `block in execute_exercise'
from rbtest.rb:18:in `each'
from rbtest.rb:18:in `execute_exercise'
from rbtest.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

The attempts I've made are:

```rb
my_stocks.each {|symbol,price| puts symbol if price > 500}
for q, e in my_stocks.to_i < 500
      puts e
    end
```

I expect the values to print from the hash, but it's obvious that I'm missing something here. I can't convert the fixnum into hash without `.to_h`, but does that even work? Am I just misunderstanding for loops or is it something else?

Comment: We don't have "guards" like other languages, rather we generally deal with iteration using chained methods. Really simple way though is your first code with `puts j if j[:price] > 500`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking Ruby to do way too much at once here:

```
for q, e in my_stocks.to_i < 500
```

That really doesn't make any sense. `for` iterates over a container. `to_i` returns an integer. `x.to_i < n` returns a boolean. You can't iterate over a boolean. Plus, `my_stocks` is a Hash and it doesn't do `to_i`, so this whole line is not something Ruby can make sense of.

Instead think about the problem differently. The Ruby way is to break this down into steps. First, find all stocks over a particular value:

```
my_stocks.select do |_name, data|
  data['price'] > 500
end.each do |name, data|
  # ... print or whatever
end
```

Where this taps into [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) to help solve the problem in two stages. `select` to filter, `each` to iterate. In Ruby `for` isn't really used, it's really never the best tool for the job.

The real power of Enumerable is that you can chain one operation right into the next. `end.each` might look very odd to someone unfamiliar with Ruby, but that's really how Ruby handles complex operations with ease.

For example, to filter and sort by price (highest to lowest) is only a small modification:

```
my_stocks.select do |_name, data|
  data['price'] > 500
end.sort_by do |_name, data|
  -data['price']
end.each do |name, data|
  # ... print or whatever
end
```

The `-data['price']` part is an easy way of avoiding having to reverse the values later. Normally it sorts in increasing order, so inverting sorts in decreasing as the highest value becomes the lowest.

Comment: I see. So, whereas I'm used to using `for` loops in other languages, Ruby is easier using the supplied `.each` method? So `do` is defining which parameters to collect and the `data` parameter specifies which area of the hash to search? You're also correct in assuming that `end.sort` or `end.each` looks foreign to me. How is it possible to do that?

Comment: Please see the documentation on https://ruby-doc.com/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html as the answer references.  But these methods do what their names imply and can operate on objects which are Enumerable (i.e. Hash or Array) .  There are more clunky ways to do loops but this is more the Ruby convention for your use case.

Comment: Other languages use `for` because it's all they've got. Some like JavaScript have a mix: `for (...) { ... }` and `array.forEach(function(e) { ... })` where you can pick the one you prefer. In Ruby `for` is all but useless since Enumerable does everything it can do and far, far more, to the point where if one day it got deleted from the language I'm not sure anyone would notice. `.each` has a block that receives a single argument, the element being iterated, but there's also `each_with_index` (element, index) and `each_with_object` (element, arbitrary object) as but two examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the loop syntax like this but just use "next" to skip iteration on item who's price doesn't meet your requirement:

```
for q, e in my_stocks
  next unless e['price'] > 500 
  puts q
  puts e
end
```

This will output:

```
Google
{"symbol"=>"GOOG", "price"=>1150}
Amazon
{"symbol"=>"AMZN", "price"=>1250}
```